# "Featured widget" model design

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a widget model that represents items that a client can view from my website.  I'd like to have several featured widgets that are displayed differently and have extra information about them.  How would you recommend representing this additional information and connecting it to its corresponding widget?

I have seen a few questions about featured elements but they all add "featured" attributes to the original model.  I don't think this is a good idea in this case since featured widgets will have many extra pieces of info and there are very few featured widgets relative to total widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Have a collection of "featured" things.

This is general purpose enough it could be used for any domain model, all you need is a `widget_id` and any metadata required by your usecase.

It could also be implemented as a `Featurable` mixin.

Comment: Thanks, Dave!  Both options make sense at a high level but my novice brain is struggling with the specifics.  I particularly like the mixin approach.  The related example I keep coming across is Taggable which adds a one-to-many relationship to tags.  That makes a lot of sense to me but in the case I'm describing, I can't seem to come up with a sensible way to model the relationship between widgets and featured widgets.  Seems like an is-a relationship.  Any pointers to useful resources for thinking about this would be appreciated.

Comment: Less an is-a than a featurable has-a featured "thing", or widget in your case.